# SSRS Report - When fixed column headers and rows expanded they jump under header

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am having a problem with SSRS 2008 reports that have fixed column headers. Whenever a report has these fixed column headers and also has rows that get expanded, the row that gets expanded jumps underneath the header. The Row would be moving to the correct place if the header wasn't there but because the header is there the row that gets expanded and some of the next row are hidden by the header.

**Example**

```
CREATE TABLE Company( companyID INT , companyName VARCHAR(30), PRIMARY KEY(companyID) ) GO

CREATE TABLE OrderDetails( orderID INT, orderDesc VARCHAR(30), orderQty INT, companyID INT, FOREIGN KEY(companyID) REFERENCES Company(companyID), PRIMARY KEY(orderID) ) GO

INSERT INTO Company SELECT 1, 'Joe Soap' GO INSERT INTO Company SELECT 2, 'Billy Bob' GO INSERT INTO OrderDetails SELECT 1, 'Toys', 1, 1 GO INSERT INTO OrderDetails SELECT 2, 'Boxes', 3, 1 GO INSERT INTO OrderDetails SELECT 3, 'Sweets', 2, 1 GO INSERT INTO OrderDetails SELECT 4, 'Forks', 1, 2 GO INSERT INTO OrderDetails SELECT 5, 'OrderDetails', 5, 2 GO

CREATE PROC MyDataSource AS SELECT companyName, orderDesc, orderQty FROM Company c JOIN OrderDetails o ON c.CompanyID = o.CompanyID GO

EXEC MyDataSource
```

If you run the above script then you will get the following results back from the proc.

```
> companyName orderDesc orderQty  
> Joe Soap  Toys  1  
> Joe Soap  Boxes  3  
> Joe Soap  Sweets  2  
> Billy Bob  Forks  1 
> Billy Bob  OrderDetails 5
```

If you create a report that uses this proc as a datasource and you group it by the company and add fixed headers then you will be able to re create the problem. When the report is shown for the first time then it should only show to rows, the company names, Joe soap and Billy Bob. If you expand one of these rows to show the detail the the row with the company name in it will go under the fixed header of the report.

I was wondering if there is anything I can do to prevent this or if this is just another one of those irritating SSRS bugs.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug has now been fixed in the next release  SQL 2008 R2